# Calling a function using ng-init inside ng-repeat only gets the result of the last item in the loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change a progress bar content for each line in my table. To do so I used ng-init inside ng-repeat here is my code :

The view :

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="p in projetsListe" ng-init={{progressBar($index)}}>
  <td>
  <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" ng-click="p.expanded = !p.expanded" expand data-toggle="collapse" id="{{p.IdProjet}}" data-target=".{{p.IdProjet}}">
  <span ng-bind="p.expanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
  </button>
  </td>
  <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
  <td>{{p.Responsable}}</td>
  <td>{{trestant[$index]}}</td>
  <td><div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" id="pg1" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"><label id="l1"></label>
       </div>
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" id="pg2" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
       </div>
       <label style="font-size :10px"><i class="fa fa-circle" style ="color : #df6d69"></i> Temps Passé : {{tpasse[$index]}}h</label>
                               &nbsp &nbsp
       <label style="font-size :10px"><i class="fa fa-circle" style ="color : green"></i> Temps Prévu : {{tprev[$index]}}h</label>
   </td>
</tr>
```

My function :

```
 $scope.progressBar= function(i){   
  var tpa;
        var p1 = document.getElementById('pg1');
        var p2 = document.getElementById('pg2');
        var l1 = document.getElementById('l1');
        tpa = ($scope.tpasse[i]*100)/$scope.tprev[i];
           if(tpa<=100){
             p1.style.width =  tpa + '%';
             p2.style.width =  100-tpa + '%';
             l1.innerHTML = " ";
           }
           else{
             p1.style.width = '100' +'%';   
             l1.innerHTML = "Attention : Temps prévu dépassé !";
           }  
 };
```

In the result I only get the data of the last line of the table and it appears in the first line:

[image]

This result should appear in the second line which is now empty, while the first one should have different result. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue ?

Here is a plunker that illustrates this problem : https://plnkr.co/edit/nGxqMOPejKMINb89Ewwx?p=preview

Comment: can u show this in a plunker

Comment: You can't repeat element ID's in a page. Your whole approach is wrong. There should be no use of DOM code in controller. Can be done using `ng-style` and no need for `ng-init` , that is not what it is for

Comment: @charlietfl I am new to angular so I am using what I know so far, you mean ng-style can solve my problem ?

Comment: You need to completely rethink how you coded things before when using angular. Strongly suggest reading : [Thinking in AngularJS if I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for the advice, but for now i need a solution to this particular case

Comment: Suggest you study some angular tutorials

Comment: @SaEChowdary  here is the link to a plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/nGxqMOPejKMINb89Ewwx?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with you cod is that you have same id for different elements. And that is not allowed so only your progress bars are not coming properly. Below is the code that solves your problem. But what i would suggest is that there are other issues as well with your code for eg you are using interpolation with `ng-init={{}progressBar($index)}` but this will throw error as `progressBar returns nothing`. I think you need to review you code properly.

```
// Code goes here
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.tpasse = ['5049','26','100'];
$scope.tprev = ['688','336','400'];

$scope.projetsListe = [
    {
      "NomProjet" : "Project1",
      "ResponsableApitech" : "Jean"

    },

    {
     "NomProjet" : "Project2", 
     "ResponsableApitech" : "Edward"

    },

    {
     "NomProjet" : "Project2", 
     "ResponsableApitech" : "Edward"

    }
];
console.log($scope.projetsListe);

 $scope.progressBar= function(i){   
        var tpa;
        var p1 = document.getElementById('pg'+i);
        var p2 = document.getElementById('pgb'+i);
        var l1 = document.getElementById('l'+i);

        tpa = ($scope.tpasse[i]*100)/$scope.tprev[i];
           if(tpa<=100){
             p1.style.width =  tpa + '%';
             p2.style.width =  100-tpa + '%';
             l1.innerHTML = " ";
           }
           else{
             p1.style.width = '100' +'%';   
             l1.innerHTML = "Attention : You have reached the limits!";
           }  
 };
});
```

```
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nom</th>
          <th>Responsable</th>
          <th>Progress</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in projetsListe track by $index">
          <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
          <td>{{p.ResponsableApitech}}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="progress" ng-init="{{progressBar($index)}}">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" id="pg{{$index}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                <label id="l{{$index}}"></label>
              </div>
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" id="pgb{{$index}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
            <label style="font-size :10px"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color : #df6d69"></i> Temps Passé : {{tpasse[$index]}}h</label> &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <label style="font-size :10px"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color : green"></i> Temps Prévu : {{tprev[$index]}}h</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4IDTl8DVafMzYOImJhfi?p=preview)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly you literally saved me, I will indeed review my code to avoid these issues

Answer (score 1):

I know, you've already accepted the answer, but I still want to suggest you to use [`components`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) approach (because you are using angularjs 1.5+) to solve your problem. There a few things in your code that looks not very good: `ngInit` adds unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates and you can avoid using it because components have a well-defined lifecycle and you can use `$onChanges` hook to re-draw your progress bar. Also manipulating DOM inside the controller is not an angular-way of working with your views, it is better to use [`ngStyle` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) in your case. Here is a working example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.projetsListe = [
    {
      NomProjet : "Project1",
      ResponsableApitech : "Jean",
      tpasse: 5049,
      tprev: 688
    }, {
      NomProjet : "Project2", 
      ResponsableApitech : "Edward",
      tpasse: 26,
      tprev: 336
    }, {
      NomProjet : "Project4", 
      ResponsableApitech : "Edward",
      tpasse: 177,
      tprev: 336
    }
  ];
})
.component('progressBar', {
  templateUrl: "progress-bar.html",
  bindings: {
    project: '<'
  },
  controller: 'ProgressBarCtrl'
})
.controller('ProgressBarCtrl', [function ProgressBarCtrl (){
  var ctrl = this;
  
  ctrl.$onChanges = onChanges;

  ctrl.styles = {};
  
  function onChanges(changesObject){
    ctrl.styles = getStyles(ctrl.project);
  }
  
  function getStyles(project){
      var tpa, styles = {};
      tpa = (project.tpasse*100) / project.tprev;
 
      if (tpa <= 100){
        styles = {
          p1Width: tpa + '%',
          p2Width: 100-tpa + '%',
          l1innerHTML: " "
        };
      } else{
        styles = {
          p1Width: '100%',
          l1innerHTML: "Attention : You have reached the limits!"
        };
      } 
      
     return styles;
  }
  
  return ctrl;
  
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/tether@1.2.4/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Responsable</th>
        <th>Progress</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="p in projetsListe">
       <td>{{p.NomProjet}}</td>
       <td>{{p.ResponsableApitech}}</td>
       <td>
         <progress-bar project="p"></progress-bar>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="progress-bar.html">
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" ng-style="{'width': $ctrl.styles.p1Width}" role="progressbar"
         aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="100">
        <label>{{$ctrl.styles.l1innerHTML}}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" ng-style="{'width': $ctrl.styles.p2Width}"
         role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40"
         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<label style="font-size :10px"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color : #df6d69"></i> The actual Time spent :
    {{$ctrl.project.tpasse}}h</label>
&nbsp; &nbsp;
<label style="font-size :10px"><i class="fa fa-circle" style="color : green"></i> The Initial expected time :
    {{$ctrl.project.tprev}}h</label>
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sure is a more proper way to do it, and it helped me understand the `ngStyle` directive logic, Thank you very much